# how can a function move at the top of the scope in which it is defined

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I was reading the book **`javascript : The Good Parts`**, under **The function Statement Versus the function Expression**, section **B.9**. There is a line which says that

> function statements are subject to hoisting. This means that
>   regardless of where a function is placed, it is moved to the top of
>   the scope in which it is defined. This relaxes the requirement that
>   functions should be declared before used, which I think leads to
>   sloppiness

so according to this i did a simple experiment as follows:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">


var x = function(){

    alert(s);

    var s = function(){
        return 'sanmevg'; 
    }

};  
</script>   

<body>


<button onclick="x();">click here</button>  

</body></html>
```

Now according to this book it clearly states that:

> it is moved to the top of
>   the scope in which it is defined. This relaxes the requirement that
>   functions should be declared before used

so this means that when that button is clicked then there should be an `alert` saying `sanmveg`. but the result was unexpected, it return `Undefined`.

### My Questions

**1)** Should i take those statement written by `Douglas Crockford` ,correct for some special case(if yes then it would be so kind enough to tell me those cases)?

**2)** Is it reflecting some other meaning?

**3)** Do i have done something wrong in my experiment?

---

Thank you for all your answers!

Comment: thank you @Brad Larson for your edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that is not a function declaration :

```
var s = function(){
    return 'sanmevg'; 
}
```

it is an anonymous function assigned to a variable. Change it to that and it will work :

```
function s(){
    return 'sanmevg'; 
}
```

---

As stated by [Phylax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3489419/phylax) :

> *"Note that* `var s` *will be hoisted. That is why the* `alert()` *show* `undefined` *instead of an error. But the assigned will stay where it is."*

Comment: Note that `var s` will be hoisted. That is why the `alert()` show undefined instead of an error. But the assigned will stay where it is.

Comment: @phylax I think that's a important note, may I include it in the answer?

Comment: okey thanks... and by the way from your line `it is an anonymous function assigned to a variable` can i write `var s = function s(){..}`  because a non-anonymous function is assined to a variable

Comment: @anni yes you can! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname/338053#338053

Answer (score 0):

What you typed is a function expression and not a function declaration.

A function declaration gets hoisted, which is why you can call the function above where you define it and what you were reading about.

```
function myFunction(){
  alert('myFunction');
}
```

However, a function expression is what you typed. The declared variable gets hoisted, yet the function assignment remains in place.

```
var myFunction = function(){
  alert('myFunction');
}
```